# Unpacking compressed package file after R package installation

Tags: r, compression, r-package, data-storage

I'd like to include a large data file in my R package. This file is located in the `inst` directory, and it is compressed. My goal is to yield a smaller package size on our local repository while eliminating decompression at attachment time.

Every time my package is attached, it must decompress the file which takes a few seconds.

Is there a way to decompress this file permanently upon installation of my package?

Comment: It decompresses on every `library()`? That's surprising to me. I thought the `inst` folder should just be copied to the package directory once during `install.packages()`. It should just be a direct copy, it shouldn't attempt to decompress it at all. Do you have code that runs on load that does something with the file? Maybe see http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: To clarify, I decompress the file when it is needed using a separate mechanism. My question is if it can be unpacked into a permanent uncompressed state somewhere in the library.

Comment: Oh. I see. Well, package state should be immutable after installation. But perhaps you could add a Makefile step to do the decompression during install.packages(). Normally that's when compilation would happen but I guess in theory you could transform data then.

Comment: Not offering a solution, but I think that the file must be uncompressed at the installation once and for all. If you do it at the first usage, keep in mind that in many cases the package is installed in a system folder which the user might not be able to write to. So you should decompress the file locally, but also your mechanism that loads it must be aware of the location. Finding a way to decompress the file on the installation is the way to go imo.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't save in `inst/` and use usethis to save data

I'd strongly recommend using [`usethis::use_data`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_data.html) to save data in a R package setting. With `use_data()`, it saves to `data/`. You can also set the compress method. For your purpose, I'd suggest `method = "xz"` (see the [`save`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/save) documentation on compression).

The other thing to do is set `LazyData: false` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, then when you want to access the data, use `data("dataname", package = "yourpackage")` to load it.

See the [chapter on Data](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data) in the R Packages book. It helps clarify many things.

Comment: Thanks. Does this method decompress the data once at installation time or every time the package is attached?

Comment: See my edits. I don't believe it decompresses, but it might depending on the method. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Megatron I believe neither of those occurs, but rather it is decompressed every time the data is **used**. At least, that's how I read [Hadley's R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-data) (linked to in @Luke 's answer): "If the DESCRIPTION contains LazyData: true, then datasets will be lazily loaded. This means that they won’t occupy any memory until you use them." Of course, if you use this data in `.onAttach()`, then I believe it would be decompressed every time the package is attached.